# Multiple capturing groups within non-capturing group using Python regexes

Tags: python, regex, capturing-group

I have the following code using multiple capturing groups within a non-capturing group:

```
>>> regex = r'(?:a ([ac]+)|b ([bd]+))'
>>> re.match(regex, 'a caca').groups()
('caca', None)
>>> re.match(regex, 'b bdbd').groups()
(None, 'bdbd')
```

How can I change the code so it outputs either `('caca')` or `('bdbd')`?

Comment: With PyPi regex, you may get `('caca',)` and `('bdbd',)`

Comment: Under which conditions? Cannot produce using PyPi regex v2020.6.8.

Comment: `r'(?|a ([ac]+)|b ([bd]+))'`

Comment: I posted [an answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62498576/3832970) since you seem to get interested. I really believe Python should be shipped with regex module built-in, it is so much faster, stable and powerful than `re` when it comes to sophisticated pattern matching or handling large texts that it must be part of the default installation bundle in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.

To get the capture always as group 1 can use a lookahead to do the match and then a separate capturing group to capture:

```
(?:a (?=[ac]+)|b (?=[bd]+))(.*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bb7C6O/1/)

Or in Python3:

```
>>> regex=r'(?:a (?=[ac]+)|b (?=[bd]+))(.*)'
>>> (?:a (?=[ac]+)|b (?=[bd]+))(.*)
>>> re.match(regex, 'a caca').groups()
('caca',)
>>> re.match(regex, 'b bdbd').groups()
('bdbd',)
```

Comment: Warning: your regex is capturing next characters too (due to the .* )

Comment: A character class or additional regex can be added to fix that. OP did not state what exactly he is looking for there...

Comment: Right, i was trying to find a solution to cover exactly his match, but this wasn't the right path.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to get the matches using a lookbehind without a capturing group:

```
(?<=a )[ac]+|(?<=b )[bd]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LaSBJi/1)

For example

```
import re

pattern = r'(?<=a )[ac]+|(?<=b )[bd]+'
print (re.search(pattern, 'a caca').group())
print (re.search(pattern, 'b bdbd').group())
```

Output

```
caca
bdbd
```

Comment: Yes, however, lookbehind patterns should match strings of the same length if you use `re`. Again, with PyPi regex, it will become much more scalable since lookbehind pattern with `regex` can match strings of any length.

Comment: That is true, it is not that flexible.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a **[branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html)** with [PyPi `regex` module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

> [Alternatives](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) inside a branch reset group share the same capturing groups. The syntax is `(?|regex)` where `(?|` opens the group and regex is any regular expression. If you don’t use any alternation or capturing groups inside the branch reset group, then its special function doesn’t come into play. It then acts as a [non-capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncapture).

The regex will look like

```
(?|a ([ac]+)|b ([bd]+))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uUZTS5/1). See the [Python 3 demo](https://tio.run/##dcqxCoQwDADQ3a/I1gTF5ebDDxGHpC3qcLbEChX671WcXG57w4tnWsL2qXX9xaAJ1M8@N5rhC2pwKAw4sp1aKnJL3C0yTdR1S4BP7nfPahfU3IFhsGzZUD9rOOKORP@vgDhx71vrBQ):

```
import regex
rx = r'(?|a ([ac]+)|b ([bd]+))'
print (regex.search(rx, 'a caca').groups()) # => ('caca',)
print (regex.search(rx, 'b bdbd').groups()) # => ('bdbd',)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the problem the other way around:

```
((?:a [ac]+)|(?:b [bd]+))
^ ^         ^ ^
| |         | other exact match
| |         OR
| not capturing for exact match
capture everything
```

A easier look: [https://regex101.com/r/e3bK2B/1/](https://regex101.com/r/e3bK2B/1)

Comment: When I try it, this captures the whole of `a caca`; the OP only wants to capture the `caca` part.

Comment: Thanks. Enjoyed the explanation. But @alaniwi is right.

Comment: Sorry, i tried to find another solution, but didn't found any.